# Query to count a column based on the previous row's column result

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with this data:
[image]

```sql
create table my_table (
    month varchar(2),
    services integer null,
    s_registered integer,
    s_terminated integer
);

insert into my_table(month, services, s_registered, s_terminated) values
    ('01', 395, 14, 14),
    ('02', null, 5, 9),
    ('03', null, 19, 15),
    ('04', null, 30, 11),
    ('05', null, 13, 15),
    ('06', null, 8, 11),
    ('07', null, 10, 17),
    ('08', null, 13, 17),
    ('09', null, 5, 10),
    ('10', null, 10, 19),
    ('11', null, 7, 22),
    ('12', null, 18, 13);
```

You can see the `services` column and I need a query to select the result with the calculated `services` in each row.
The `services` column is equal to `services + s_registered - s_termination` of the previous row.[image]

I tried using the window cte LAG() function, but it only worked once. It correctly accepts the first `services` column, but on the next iteration the LAG takes the column as null.

I think this issue can be resolved with recursive CTE, do you have any ideas?:)

Comment: Please add sample data as text which we can use as opposed to images which we can't..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed do this with a recursive CTE.  For example, you could use this as a base and customise it for your needs:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM mytable where month = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        mytable.month,
        cte.services + cte.s_registered - cte.s_terminated,
        mytable.s_registered,
        mytable.s_terminated
    FROM cte
    INNER JOIN mytable ON cte.month + 1 = mytable.month
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

Comment: That it is! thank you, Rob:)

Answer (score 2):

You do not want a recursive cte for this, you can simply use the SUM window function:

```
select
    month,
    sum(coalesce(services,0) + s_registered - s_terminated) over (order by month rows unbounded preceding) services,
    s_registered,
    s_terminated
from my_table
order by month;
```

Comment: @Charlieface good point, thanks

Comment: this is actually an interesting idea, but it works the same way as LAG(). It also count every row incuding the first one, which I dont need to do. And if you try to use `(order by month row 1 preceding)` than you'll see, on the second row it's calculating  `services` from the first row, but on the third row the expr `services OVER(row 1 preceding)` is null.

In my case, I guess the only solution is recursive cte

Comment: @RomanSamarsky it works on the data you showed; can you show data where it doesn't work?  if you have services set on other rows and you want to ignore them, you can do something like `first_value(services) over (order by month) + sum(s_registered - s_terminated) over (order by month rows unbounded preceding)`  if you need to ignore s_registered and s_terminated for the first row, then do `first_value(services - s_registered + s_terminated) over (order by month) + sum(s_registered - s_terminated) over (order by month rows unbounded preceding)` to include them in the sum, but first reverse them